# Focus Gained and Focus Lost event

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield

I have 4 JTextfields in my java swing form. The problem is I need to move the Focus from one JTextField to other through java code not by using tab key.

If the Focus gained by JTextField2 means the content in the JTextField2 need to be selected. I don't know how to do this plz put your proper code associate with this issue

Comment: *"plz put your proper code"* Please put *your* best attempt in the form of an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Adding what you have tried after reading [How to Use the Focus Subsystem](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html) & the [JTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html) docs (with special attention to any find on 'select') would not hurt either.  Also note this is not a text message, so it is 'please' rather than 'plz'.

Comment: @sjohnfernandas - do you actually read the answers because you do not accept or respond to any of them (for this and your other questions)? If you keep this up people will stop helping you...

Answer (score 1):

You can call [`requestFocusInWindow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow%28%29) for the textfield you want focus.

Answer (score 1):

that could be little bit complicated

you have to wrap and delay your [Action](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) or [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) into `invokeLater()`, and put inside (most safiest way is to set there follows code lines)

- `JTextField2.setText(JTextField2.getText);`

and

- `JTextField2.selectAll();`

edit to @Andrew Thompson

```
private FocusListener fcsListener = new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            dumpInfo(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            //dumpInfo(e);
        }

        private void dumpInfo(FocusEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Source  : " + name(e.getComponent()));
            System.out.println("Opposite : " + name(e.getOppositeComponent()));
            System.out.println("Temporary: " + e.isTemporary());
            Component c = e.getComponent();//works for editable JComboBox too
            if (c instanceof JFormattedTextField) {
                ((JFormattedTextField) c).selectAll();
            } else if (c instanceof JTextField) {
                ((JTextField) c).selectAll();
            }//both methods not correct required setText(getText()) inside invokeLater
        }

        private String name(Component c) {
            return (c == null) ? null : c.getName();
        }
    };
```

Comment: `JTextField2.setText(JTextField2.getText);`  Wouldn't that either have no effect or go into an infinite loop?

Comment: if you running whatever inside EDT, or periodically updating another JComponent (with attached Listeners) from the background task, then you can pretty lost Focus and you have to forcing Focus with these two code lined wrapped inside invokeLater, work for me for all TextComponent excluding JTextPane

Comment: Your edit makes sense, but then it does not seem to relate to calling an instance of a text field to set it to the text of ..itself.