# How to detect when user finished typing in jTextpane in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I have a document which is inside a `jTextPane` and it includes some components as labels in it. When user adds text in the document by tying, the addresses of components change, so I have to run a method after user finished typing to reread all the component places at least only the ones that are after the caretPosition.is there any way to detect when user finished typing in jTextpane to run my update function. If I run it each time after every key pressed, it takes a long time for inserting each letter while typing.

Comment: when the textpane loses the focus (focus lost event)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8544461/focus-gained-and-focus-lost-event

Comment: Thanks man, worked, that was awesome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the JTextPane's [inputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setInputVerifier%28javax.swing.InputVerifier%29) to an instance of your own subclass of [InputVerifier](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html).  This has the advantage that you can set some controls (such as a "Cancel" button) to refrain from triggering it, using [setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setVerifyInputWhenFocusTarget%28boolean%29).